# Render FreeType text with flipped ortho, difference between top and baseline of glyph

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

I am working on a project where I implement a FreeType rendering object to draw text of which the rendering environment is specified with an orthographic projection matrix:

```
glm::ortho(0, Width, Height, 0);
```

This makes sure the coordinates are similar to standard GUI systems with `(0,0)` being the top-left part of the window instead of the bottom-left.

However when rendering using FreeType, things get difficult, because FreeType operates with their origin at the bottom-left of a glyph (minus the descender). My issue is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353472/render-freetype-gl-text-with-flipped-projection but no answer was yet provided and his solution was not to my liking (the used library is also slightly different, I assume he is using a wrapper).

So I render my text as follows:

```
renderText("Testing 123 if text performs sufficiently", 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Of which `renderText` function contains:

```
renderText(const GLchar *text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat sx, GLfloat sy)
{
    [...]
    GLfloat xpos = x + glyph->bitmap_left * sx; 
    GLfloat ypos = y - glyph->bitmap_top * sy; 
    GLfloat w = glyph->bitmap.width * sx;
    GLfloat h = glyph->bitmap.rows * sy;
    // Update VBO
    GLfloat vertices[4][4] = {
        { xpos,     ypos,       0, 0 },
        { xpos + w, ypos,       1, 0 },
        { xpos,     ypos + h,   0, 1 },
        { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1, 1 }
    };
    [...]
}
```

If I render it like this, it will render the text below the y coordinate of `0` so it won't be visible unless I add an offset to the y coordinate. So looking at FreeType's glyph metrics:

[image: glyph metrics from FreeType]

I want to offset the y position by a positive amount equal to the difference between the origin and the top of the glyph image so it always neatly renders the text at my given position. Looking at the image I believe this to be the yMax value so I added the following statement to the code before updating the VBO:

```
ypos += (glyph->face->bbox.yMax >> 6) * sy;
```

Which seemed to fix the issue when I loaded the FreeType glyphs with font size 24, but as soon as I tried to use different font sizes it failed to work as this image shows:

[image: font size differences]

As you can see, it clearly doesn't work as I thought it would. I've been thouroughly searching through FreeType's documentation if I was missing something, but I could not find it. Am I using the wrong metrics (using Ascender didn't work as well)?

Comment: `glyph->face->bbox.yMax` is 26.6 fixed-point by default. What exactly is the value of `sy`? **1.0 / 64.0**?

Comment: Oh sorry, yea I should bitshift it by 6 (forgot to add that to code). Sx and sY are scaling values (1.0f, in function call) I'll add those as well to make things more clear

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to offset the y position by a positive amount equal to the difference between the origin and the top of the glyph image so it always neatly renders the text at my given position. Looking at the image I believe this to be the `yMax` value so I added the following statement to the code before updating the VBO:

```
    ypos += (glyph->face->bbox.yMax >> 6) * sy;
```

---

In actuality, `yMax` is not what you are interested in. You could use `yMax - yMin` to find the height of your glyph, but that is really all it is good for.

#### From the FreeType 2 API documentation, [`FT_GlyphSlotRec::bitmap_top`](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_GlyphSlotRec) is:

> The bitmap's top bearing expressed in integer pixels. Remember that this is the distance from the baseline to the top-most glyph scanline, upwards y coordinates being **positive**.

Look at the image you included in your question again, that is effectively `bearingY`. Your problem is that you are subtracting this value from your `ypos` when you should not be. You do need the value as I will explain below, but you definitely do not want to subtract it.

#### If you eliminate `bitmap_top` from your calculation of `ypos` you get the following:

[image: False alignment]

Which is obviously incorrect because it ignores differences in ascent between each character in your string.

#### Now, take a close look at the following correctly aligned diagram:

[image]

In the diagram above, I have illustrated your string's top-most line in red, bottom-most in green and the baseline for all of your glyphs in grey.

As you can see, the capital letter `'T'` has the greatest ascent and this generalization holds true for most fonts. Directly below the red line, I have illustrated the difference in ascent between capital `'T'` and the current letter as the yellow area. This is the important quantity that you must calculate to properly align your string.

#### The yellow region in the correctly aligned figure above can be calculated thus:

```
    Chars['T'].bitmap_top - glyph->bitmap_top
```

If you stop subtracting `glyph->bitmap_top` from `ypos` and add the value above, you should get the same results as the correctly aligned diagram.

---

For bonus points, if you want to align your text to the ***bottom*** of the screen, the concept is very similar only you are interested in the difference between the character with the greatest descent (often lowercase `'g'`) and the current character. That is the distance between the grey baseline and the green line and can be expressed as `height - bearingY` in your glyph metrics figure.

#### You should be able to compute descent using this:

```
(glyph->metrics.height >> 6) - glyph->bitmap_top // bitmap_top is in integer coords
```

Comment: Unfortunately if I do `ypos += (glyph->metrics.height >> 6) - glyph->bitmap_top;` the characters are still correct next to each other, but the string is position below y = 0.0f. As you can see here: http://prntscr.com/5h9rk7

Comment: @Djemon: Oh, I see now. I was confused because the distance you were talking about (difference between origin and the top of the glyph image) is what you already have when you use `glyph->bitmap_top`. You _already_ subtracted the distance you are talking about from your `ypos`. I will re-examine the question in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: @Djemon: I strongly suspect that subtracting `glyph->bitmap_top` from `ypos` when you compute the position is to blame here. Can you try removing that part of your code altogether? So that `ypos` is simply `y`?

Comment: Removing `glyph->bitmap_top` is probably the way to go. I removed it and this is the result: http://prntscr.com/5hhhvp . The positioning is now correct, but unfortunately the specific glyphs aren't positioned correctly anymore. I tried to mitigate the issue by taking the difference between either `bitmap_top`  and `height` or `height` - `yMax` which I add to the `yPos` but still with incorrect positioning. I'm closer I believe, but I still can't find any metric on the image that fixes the current situation.

Comment: @Djemon: To solve that, you need to know the difference in ascent between the largest character in your string. `'T'` almost always has the greatest ascent. Try adding the difference in `bitmap_top` of the letter `'T'` and the letter you are currently drawing to `yPos`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the code to `yPos = y + (Chars['T'].bitmap_top - glyph->bitmap_top) * sy` and it works perfectly for all different font sizes. If you edit this in your answer I'll gladly accept it. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Djemon: Just so you know, I have a suspicion that your horizontal spacing is wrong as well for similar reasons. There is a horizontal advance (in 26.6 coordinates) that you would use to advance the X coordinate after each of your characters and that advance already includes the value of `bitmap_left` (which is called `bearingX` in the glyph metrics diagram). Consequently, each of your characters is probably spaced slightly farther apart than they should be and your text is never properly aligned to the left of the screen (you can see that `'T'` is never fully left in any of your screenshots).

Comment: You're right, I used the `bitmap_left` since an online tutorial used that for the `xPos` and never looked back (the one thing that changed from the tutorial was that I had a flipped y ortho-perspective). Removing the `bitmap_left` from the `xPos` moves the glyphs closer together which looks more natural :) Thanks again.