# How do I align Glyphs along the baseline with Freetype?

Tags: c++, opengl, fonts, text-rendering, freetype2

I have written a function that creates an image from a font using Freetype2. My goal is to create an OpenGL-texture with all characters from the font. But first, I want to make sure the texture gets created properly, thus I store it as an image with stb_image_write for now.  This is my progress so far:

[image: The first few letters from the image]

As you can see, the glyphs are not aligned along the baseline, but along the top of the image. So I decided to introduce a variable called "yOffset", which describes the amount of pixels that each glyph has to be moved down to align them properly.

According to an answer in [Render FreeType text with flipped ortho, difference between top and baseline of glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469321/render-freetype-text-with-flipped-ortho-difference-between-top-and-baseline-of), this offset can be calculated with

```
yOffset = (Glyph with highest y-Bearing)->bitmap_top - glyph->bitmap_top
```

This value is stored in "maxAscent" with the first loop, which finds out the metrics of each glyph.

Here's a visual representation of the glyph-metrics:

[image]

Here's my function:

```
static void loadFontImage(const std::string& fontPath, unsigned int fontSize, const std::string& imagePath) {
        FT_Library library;
        FT_Face face;

        unsigned int imageWidth = 0;
        unsigned int imageHeight = 0;
        unsigned int maxAscent = 0;

        if (FT_Init_FreeType(&library)) {
            std::cerr << "Could not initialize font library" << std::endl;
            std::exit(-1);
        }

        if (FT_New_Face(library, fontPath.c_str(), 0, &face)) {
            std::cerr << "Could not load font '" << fontPath << "'" << std::endl;
            std::exit(-1);
        }

        FT_Set_Char_Size(face, 0, fontSize * 64, 300, 300);

        FT_GlyphSlot glyph = face->glyph;

        for (unsigned int c = 32; c < 256; c++) {
            if (c == 127) continue;
            if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) continue;

            imageWidth += glyph->bitmap.width;

            if (glyph->bitmap.rows > (int)imageHeight) {
                imageHeight = glyph->bitmap.rows;
            }

            if (glyph->bitmap_top > (int)maxAscent) {
                maxAscent = glyph->bitmap_top;
            }
        }

        unsigned int size = imageWidth * imageHeight;
        unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[size];
        unsigned int xOffset = 0;
        unsigned int yOffset = 0;

        for (unsigned int c = 32; c < 256; c++) {
            if (c == 127) continue;
            if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) continue;

            yOffset = maxAscent - glyph->bitmap_top;

            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < glyph->bitmap.width; x++) {
                for (unsigned int y = 0; y < glyph->bitmap.rows; y++) {
                    unsigned int imageIndex = (x + xOffset) + (y + yOffset) * imageWidth;
                    unsigned int bitmapIndex = x + y * glyph->bitmap.width;
                    buffer[imageIndex] = glyph->bitmap.buffer[bitmapIndex];
                }
            }

            xOffset += glyph->bitmap.width;
        }

        stbi_write_png(imagePath.c_str(), imageWidth, imageHeight, 1, buffer, imageWidth);

        delete[] buffer;
    }
}
```

But since I have introduced the yOffset, an "index out of bounds"-type exception occurs only at certain glyphs, because the height of the glyph plus the yOffset is larger than the image height.

I assume this is because my formula for "maxAscent" is not correct, and therefor my yOffset is too large for certain characters. Thus my question: Is this indeed the proper formula, and if it is, what else might be wrong with my algorithm? Is there perhaps an easier way to achieve proper alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue with a simple fix, after I noticed that the actual height of the image was not calculated correctly. This is because the height of the "tallest" glyph does not represent the actual height of the image. For example, a character might be smaller than the tallest glyph, but placed higher above the baseline, and thus being out of bounds.

I introduced another variable called "maxDescent", which stores the maximum amount of pixels below the baseline. It is calculated as following in the first loop:

```
if ((glyph->metrics.height >> 6) - glyph->bitmap_top > (int)maxDescent) {
    maxDescent = (glyph->metrics.height >> 6) - glyph->bitmap_top;
}
```

Together with "maxAscent", which stores the maximum amount of pixels above the baseline, I can calculate the actual height needed for the image by simply adding them together.

```
imageHeight = maxAscent + maxDescent
```

Here's a part from the result:

[image: Resulting Font Image]

Answer (score 2):

@user12678368

Thank you for this post. It helped me a lot. However, I found two slight mistakes, that maybe you or future readers of this might find interesting:

**1.**

Since your code calculates the heighest y-Bearing, your text will be displayed at different heights, depending on what characters you use.

For example:

If you displayed the string "A______" you get exactly that. But if you only displayed "_____" this will be wedged to the top of the image.

Instead you can use:

```
maxAscent = int(face->ascender * (face->size->metrics.y_scale / 65536.0)) >> 6;
maxDescent = int(abs(face->descender * (face->size->metrics.y_scale / 65536.0))) >> 6;
```

to get the global maxAscent/maxDescent for your font (face->descender is negative (for most fonts) thus the abs() in case of your code). This way, you can also get rid of your first for-loop.

**Note:** According to the FreeType-documentation these values are not defined in fonts in a uniform way and might deviate. So your milage might vary.

**2.**

When displaying spaces, "xOffset += glyph->bitmap.width" will add a zero. Meaning: "This is a test!" will be displayed as "Thisisatest!". You can change that line to

```
xOffset += glyph->metrics.horiAdvance >> 6;
```

This will get you "This is a test!".

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30531105)